# IntelliJ : Add a class method to one of the interfaces it implements

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, editor

I have a **"C" class** that implements two interfaces (lets call them **"IAlpha"** and **"IBeta"**).

I created a new method a method on my C class that I want to push up to the IAlpha interface.

Is there a way to do this ?

I tried to use **Right click on method->Extract->Interface**, but it seems to work only to create the whole Interface from a class and not for appending.

Comment: Pull members up: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/pull-members-up.html ?

Answer (score 2):

As answered here by CrazyCoder (thanks), the solution is to :

**Right click on the method -> Refactor -> Pull members Up...**

Then you will be able to select the Interface on the dropdown menu.
[image: Intelli J Pull members up - add method to interface]